# How can I connect my Windows XP computer to my modern Comcast WIFI router?

Tags: networking, windows-xp, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

Just today I picked up an older computer running Windows XP.
I have a comcast xfinity router that runs wifi on my regular laptops but this new computer only has an ethernet port.

Plugged the ethernet cable into the router and PC, set up new connections and tried a few various methods.

No luck though.
I used to be more savvy with this sort of thing when I was younger but I have been using wifi for so long now, I have no idea how to work around XP now.

My router requires a username and password. How can I access even a list of available connects and most importantly, how do I connect to my own connection??

Comment: If you get a network icon in the tray right click it and use the repair wizard... I forgot what text was in the context menu for XP tho.

Comment: Please open the Command Prompt and run `ipconfig /all` and add the output to your question.  Do this on your XP computer AND your laptop which is successfully connected to your Xfinity modem.

Comment: Windows XP **should not** be exposed to the internet as it's not a secure OS with active exploits. If it's hardware specs are lower (likely), install a Linux distro on it that's appropriate for it's hardware specs, specifically CPU and RAM _(Ubuntu will likely be the most user friendly when coming from Windows-only - Ubuntu version [flavor] [comparison](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuFlavors) - if unsure, try [Ubuntu Desktop](https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop) first)_

Answer (score 1):

Most routers (of the type you describe) can be configured to respond to Ethernet.  Often, this is configurable using HTTP(S).  The first trick, though, is to get the IP address assigned.

Plug the computer into a LAN port (not the WAN port) of the router.

Check the IP address of the computer.  If the router has automatic addressing (e.g., DHCP/IPv4) disabled, you may need to manually assign the address.  (Approximate way to do this, quoting from my memory: Start, Control Panel, Network Connections/Adapters, choose your adapter, Properties, TCP/IP configuration.)

You should assign an IP address that is similar, but not identical, to the router.  For instance, if the router uses an address of 192.168.0.1, then use 192.168.0.5

One tricky part to this is to know the IP address that the router is using.  Your devices with Wi-Fi adapters might be helpful, although the information could be misleading if the Wi-Fi communications are using a different subnet.  (So the information could be useful, but might not be.)  You may want to go online (somehow) and look up the default IP address, username, and password for the particular router that you're using.  (Sometimes useful information is also provided on a sticker, perhaps on the bottom of the router.)

I think this answer provides you with a good general direction to head.  You might need more help, but if you do, we probably will want some more specific information (like the router's model, and whatever network settings you do know) to efficiently help provide more specific answers.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of inexpensive USB wifi adapters available. The one I've used are as easy as plug it in and install the driver.  A list of available networks should pop up. Click on your network and put in your username and password and you're connected.

Answer (score -1):

Windows XP is highly insecure, even for basic internet browsing. Consider installing a Linux distro instead.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1087907)

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. You can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174).